# Adding file to a Visual Studio C++ project from command line

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have checked [/Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/19sf6kk3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and related documentation but I haven't found any way to add an existing file, to a specific filter in an open project from the command line (C++, VS2012). I have a script that auto-generates some code and I want it to add the file to the project.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: I could create a new file in VS from the command line and write the data afterwards. But i still can't figure out how to get it in a specific filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a short script to edit the xml in the .vc(x)proj.filters file and pass in the file name to it. Though, that would still require you to unload and reload the project, as I don't think it will do a live update on the file.

Answer (score 0):

> ... I haven't found any way to add an existing file, to a specific filter in an open project from the command line (C++, VS2012)

You can use `/FI` to force an include of a file that's not included in the project's source files. I use it when porting libraries like OpenSSL can Crypto++ to Windows RT and Windows Phone. For example:

```
/FI SDKDDKVer.h /FI winapifamily.h
```

is effectively:

```
#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
#include <winapifamily.h>
```

for each source file in your project.

I'm not sure about the filter part, though. (Its not clear to me what you are doing).